# JavaScript intercept module import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I have a SPA (in Aurelia / TypeScript but that should not matter) which uses **SystemJS**. Let's say it runs at `http://spa:5000/app`.

It sometimes loads JavaScript modules like `waterservice/external.js` on demand from an external URL like `http://otherhost:5002/fetchmodule?moduleId=waterservice.external.js`. I use `SystemJS.import(url)` to do this and it works fine.

But when this external module wants to import another module with a simple `import { OtherClass } from './other-class';` this (comprehensiblely) does not work. When loaded by the SPA it looks at `http://spa:5000/app/other-class.js`. In this case I have to intercept the path/location to redirect it to `http://otherhost:5002/fetchmodule?moduleId=other-class.js`.

Note: The Typescript compilation for `waterservice/external.ts` works find because the typescript compiler can find `./other-class.ts` easily. Obviously I cannot use an absolute URL for the import.

*How can I intercept the module loading inside a module I am importing with SystemJS?*

One approach I already tested is to add a mapping in the SystemJS configuration. If I import it like `import { OtherClass } from 'other-class';` and add a mapping like `"other-class": "http://otherhost:5002/fetchmodule?moduleId=other-class"` it works. But if this approach is good, how can I add mapping dynamically at runtime?

Other approaches like a generic load url interception are welcome too.

---

**Update**

I tried to intercept SystemJS as suggest by *artem* like this

```
var systemLoader = SystemJS;
var defaultNormalize = systemLoader.normalize;
systemLoader.normalize = function(name, parentName) {
    console.error("Intercepting", name, parentName);
    return defaultNormalize(name, parentName);
}
```

This would normally not change anything but produce some console output to see what is going on. Unfortunately this seems to do change something as I get an error *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.has is not a function* inside `system.js`.

Then I tried to add mappings with `SystemJS.config({map: ...});`. Surprisingly this function works incremental, so when I call it, it does not loose the already provided mappings. So I can do:

```
System.config({map: {
   "other-class": `http://otherhost:5002/fetchModule?moduleId=other-class.js`
}});
```

This does not work with relative paths (those which start with `.` or `..`) but if I put the shared ones in the root **this works out**.

I would still prefer to intercept the loading to be able to handle more scenarios but at the moment I have no idea which `has` function is missing in the above approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I add mapping dynamically at runtime?

AFAIK SystemJS can be configured at any time just by calling

```
SystemJS.config({ map: { additional-mappings-here ... }});
```

If it does not work for you, you can override loader.normalize and add your own mapping from module ids to URLs there. Something along these lines:

```
// assuming you have one global SystemJS instance
var loader = SystemJS;

var defaultNormalize = loader.normalize;
loader.normalize = function(name, parentName) {
    if (parentName == 'your-external-module' && name == 'your-external-submodule') {
        return Promise.resolve('your-submodule-url');
    } else {
        return defaultNormalize.call(loader, name, parentName);
    }
}
```

I have no idea if this will work with typescript or not. Also, you will have to figure out what names exactly are passed to loader.normalize in your case.

Also, if you use systemjs builder to bundle your code, you will need to add that override to the loader used by builder (and that's whole another story).

Comment: Because of a public holiday I did not have time to look at this suggestion right now but will do so. Awarding the bounty because it otherwise would expire. I might come back with questions though ;)

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I have updated the question with both attempts. Do you have an idea why the interception of `normalize` produces an error in my case?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake - defaultNormalize needs `this` argument:

   defaultNoramlize.call(loader, name, parentName);